# Vuejs TypeError: Cannot read property 'telnet' of undefined (found in component: <network>)

Tags: promise, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

#### Error

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression ""tunnel-status fa "+this._applyFilters(device.telnet,null,[{"name":"networkIcon","args":[{"value":"telnet","dynamic":false}]}],false)": 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'telnet' of undefined (found in component: <network>)
```

### Components

### Parent

Here is how I call my child component (see below):

```
<network :device="device"></network>
```

The `device` object is a computed property extracted from my store:

```
device() {
    var data = null;

    if (typeof this.networks !== 'undefined' && typeof this.networks[this.site.hostname] !== 'undefined') {
        data = this.networks[this.site.hostname][this.printer.hostname];
    }

    return data;
}
```

#### Child

```
<template>
    <span class="ping hint--top-right" aria-label="ping: {{ device.ping | currency '' 2 }} ms">
        <i class="tunnel-status fa {{ device.ping | networkIcon 'ping' }}"> </i>
    </span>
    <span class="telnet hint--top-right" aria-label="telnet: {{ device.telnet | currency '' 2 }} ms">
        <i class="tunnel-status fa {{ device.telnet | networkIcon 'telnet' }}"> </i>
    </span>
</template>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
    export default {
        props: {
            device: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
                default: function () {
                    return {
                        ping: null,
                        telnet: null
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        filters: {
            networkIcon: function (probe, type) {
                let icon = 'fa-pulsing fa-fw';

                if (type == 'ping' && probe > 0) {
                    icon = 'fa-check text-success';
                }
                else if (type == 'telnet' && probe > 0) {
                    icon = 'fa-check text-primary';
                }

                return icon;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Question

The error only happens once, prior to the request that fill the `store.networks` object. I wasn't expecting this kind of error as I'm **declaring my props `device` default value**:

```
default: function () {
    return {
        ping: null,
        telnet: null
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "promise"? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the error happens before the promise resolve.